# "Put down the sword" in "The Last Samurai" movie

Tags: transcription

There is a scene with 木剣 in "The Last Samurai" movie where a samurai says "かたな ***X***":
https://youtu.be/5MQC5uCPuGE?t=75

I can't understand what is the ***X*** verb ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

He says 刀を下ろせ (katana wo orose), which means "lower your sword(s)".

See [下ろす](http://jisho.org/search/%E4%B8%8B%E3%82%8D%E3%81%99).

Here, the 'su' ending changing to 'se' makes the verb imperative.  In other words, he is giving an order, eg "lower (it)!"

The 'wo' (pronounced 'o') is an object marker, it comes after the noun that is being acted on.  In this case, 'sword(s)'.

[Thanks to chocolate for pointing out that in this context 'orosu'=lower and 'otosu'=drop]

Comment: drop だと、「（刀を地面に）落とす」という意味になりませんか。「おろせ」は「落とせ」というよりも「下げろ」(lower)という感じなので。

Comment: そうですよね。lowerは曖昧ではないので、そのほうがいいかもしれません。編集します。ありがとう